# Where to put page-specific jQuery code in Rails 4.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want to put some simple JavaScript code that uses jQuery on a particular page in a Rails 4.1 project:

```
$( "#my_div" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

However, with Rails 4.1, jQuery is included at the very end of the html by default. I know I can move that to the header or I can put the above within the function set to `window.onload` or `document.onload`. But I'm guessing there's a good reason Rails moved jQuery to the end, so I'm curious what the proper thing to do here is?

Comment: put that file in public folder and load this script on the required page. though it is not the best solution but may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

In your application.js you can change the sequence they are being called in, that sequence at time has to be changed to make everything run or to say load properly. I had to do that once and it was quite a tedious job.

Comment: I think I understood what you're saying... However, I want JavaScript code that runs in a single page only. I don't want that JavaScript code to run anywhere else. So application.js is not what I want to mess with.

Comment: Use javascript include tag on top of your layout or html view file, as <%=javascript_include_tag 'path to file'%>

Comment: The javascript include tag would still load this before the jQuery library was loaded wouldn't it?

Comment: yes, it will, if you are loading the jquery file in application then the specific partial will be loaded after the main file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have "page specific" code,, considering in theory you should have one big JS file in the end.

Your code is not "page specific", I mean, if you don't have #my_div in your page, code just won't run, but that's ok.

After this clarify, your code should be in a javascript file in app/assets/javascript and you should require it with **//= require yourfile** after jquery_ujs or what's there (don't remember right now).

You should put your code inside a "document.ready" event, which is handled in jquery in this way:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#my_div" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
  });
});
```

Additional details about document.ready can be found on [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

This ensure your code is executed only once all page is loaded (toghether with javascript, css and so on), so when you execute code, you won't have any issue.

An example application.js file may look like this:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require yourfile
//= require_tree .
```

The reason why Rails put the code at the end of html is that so your html (and CSS) can be viewed before you load javascript code (which is a heavy operation), so the user can start interacting/reading your website in this way. Also in this way you ensure everything is loaded correctly being the last element should be parsed.
If I'm not wrong, I remember something about "synchronus loading of javascript", I don't remember if it was the network request or actually loading the javascript file, but I do remember that the script tag is a **blocking** one, the browser won't keep parsing html (or render css) while it's loading your javascript file, that's the reason why it's at the end of html as last element.

**Edit 1:**
By re-reading your question, I'm afraid you are actually inserting some javascript code directly in html. If that's the case, at least insert it after jquery is included by rails.
In any case, **that practice is wrong**, unless you are building a big web application with a lot of javascript (and you are probably going to use something like requirejs), there is no reason not to have a single javascript file (multiple requests are slower than a single one, you should always merge css into a single one, same for javascript). As I said, no problem, your code can be included in **all pages**, just ensure that #my_div is present only where you actually want that code to run.

It may be better to bound your code to a class in this way (and that's probably the right way to do it):

```
$(".js-spam-text").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Sorry for the name, replace js-spam-text with whatever you want. For example js-alert-message it's a good candidate.

Comment: There are situations where you want JavaScript/jQuery code being executed only for a single page

Comment: If that's the case, do it with an **If** of some sort, you can always add a class to the body tag and execute the script for the page only if the body tag is present (or even if a specific class is anywhere present in page). Don't do it in a different way, you can definitely execute javascript code only on specific pages without splitting it into multiple javascript files. There is **no reason** not to have javascript in one file. If you need to share some data between your view and your javascript and you don't want perform an ajax call, use gon: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: I concur, there are absolutely cases when you only want that code on one page. Specifically, for partials. I understand why a person would want all javascript code centrally located for maintainability, but I don't agree with sweeping generalizations about how to do <thing> and where to store <thing>.